# Date Array For Every Day, Week, Month, Year in between 2 dates

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I am trying to create an array using PHP OOP that basically creates and array for every day, month, year within 2 dates and allocates a ticket and hours worked set at 0 for every single day that has passed.

The code I have used is:

```
class statisticsClass{

    private $DateFrom       = null;
    private $DateTo         = null;

    private $startYear      = null;
    private $startMonth     = null;
    private $startDay       = null;

    private $endYear        = null;
    private $endMonth       = null;
    private $endDay         = null;

    private $theDateDif     = null;
    private $stages         = null;

    private function makeDates(){

        if(!empty($this->DateFrom)){ 

            $this->DateFrom = $this->generals->convertDate($this->DateFrom); 

        } else {

            $this->DateFrom = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last year')) . ' 00:00:00';

        }

        if(!empty($this->DateTo)){ 

            $this->DateTo = $this->generals->convertDate($this->DateTo); 

        } else {

            $this->DateTo   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now')) . ' 23:59:59';

        }

        list($theDate, $theTime) = explode(' ', $this->DateFrom);
        list($this->startYear, $this->startMonth, $this->startDay) = explode('-', $theDate);

        list($theDate2, $theTime2) = explode(' ', $this->DateTo);
        list($this->endYear, $this->endMonth, $this->endDay) = explode('-', $theDate2);

    }

    private function removeZeros($number){

        return ltrim($number, '0');

    }

    private function chartItemVersion(){

    if($this->theDateDif <= 31){

        $this->stages = 'daily';

    } elseif($this->theDateDif > 31 && $this->theDateDif <= 183){

        $this->stages = 'weekly';

    } else {

        $this->stages = 'monthly';

    }

}

    private function addZeros($number){

        if($number < 10){

            return '0' . $number;

        }

        return $number;

    }

    private function makingQueryArray(){

        for($yearMake=$this->startYear; $yearMake<=$this->endYear; $yearMake++){

            $this->queryArray[] = intval($yearMake);

        }

        foreach($this->queryArray as $year){

            if($year === $this->startYear){

                $currentMonth = intval($this->removeZeros($this->startMonth));

                for($currentMonth; $currentMonth <= 12;$currentMonth++){

                    $this->queryArray[$year][] = (string)$this->addZeros($currentMonth);
                    $tempHowManyDays = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $this->addZeros($currentMonth), $year);

                    if($this->startYear === $this->addZeros($currentMonth)){

                        $currentDay = intval($this->removeZeros($this->startDay));

                        for($currentDay; $currentDay <= $tempHowManyDays; $currentDay){

                            $this->queryArray[$year][(string)$this->addZeros($currentMonth)][(string)$this->addZeros($currentDay)]['ticket'] = 0;
                            $this->queryArray[$year][(string)$this->addZeros($currentMonth)][(string)$this->addZeros($currentDay)]['Hours'] = 0;

                        }

                    } else {

                        for($i=1; $i<=$tempHowManyDays; $i++){

                            $this->queryArray[$year][(string)$this->addZeros($currentMonth)][(string)$this->addZeros($i)]['ticket'] = 0;
                            $this->queryArray[$year][(string)$this->addZeros($currentMonth)][(string)$this->addZeros($i)]['Hours'] = 0;
                        }

                    }

                }


            } elseif($year === $this->endYear) {

                $endMonth = intval($this->removeZeros($this->endMonth));

                for($a=1; $a <= $endMonth; $a++){

                    $this->queryArray[$year][] = (string)$this->addZeros($a);

                    if($a === $endMonth){

                        $tempHowManyDays = intval($this->removeZeros($this->endDay));

                    } else {

                        $tempHowManyDays = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $this->addZeros($a), $year);

                    }

                    for($b=1; $b<=$tempHowManyDays; $b++){

                        $this->queryArray[$year][(string)$this->addZeros($a)][(string)$this->addZeros($b)]['ticket'] = 0;
                        $this->queryArray[$year][(string)$this->addZeros($a)][(string)$this->addZeros($b)]['Hours'] = 0;

                    }

                }

            } else {

                for($a=1; $a <= 12; $a++){

                    $this->queryArray[$year][] = (string)$this->addZeros($a);
                    $tempHowManyDays = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $this->addZeros($a), $year);

                    for($b=1; $b<=$tempHowManyDays; $b++){

                        $this->queryArray[$year][(string)$this->addZeros($a)][(string)$this->addZeros($b)]['ticket'] = 0;
                        $this->queryArray[$year][(string)$this->addZeros($a)][(string)$this->addZeros($b)]['Hours'] = 0;

                    }

                }


            }

        }

        var_dump($this->queryArray);

    }

    private function dateDifference(){

        $now        = strtotime($this->DateFrom);
        $your_date  = strtotime($this->DateTo);
        $datediff   = $your_date - $now;

        $this->theDateDif = round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));

    }

    function __construct($pdo, $theArray, $generals = null){

        if($generals !== null){ $this->generals = $generals; }

        $this->pdo = $pdo;

        if(isset($theArray['DateFrom']) && !empty($theArray['DateFrom'])){ $this->DateFrom = $theArray['DateFrom']; }
        if(isset($theArray['DateTo']) && !empty($theArray['DateTo'])){ $this->DateTo = $theArray['DateTo']; }

        $this->makeDates();
        $this->dateDifference();
        $this->chartItemVersion();
        $this->makingQueryArray();

        var_dump($this->queryArray);

    }

}

$theArray = array();

$amhStatistics = new statisticsClass($pdo, $theArray, $generals);
```

I have been playing around with it for a while and can not get this array to function corectly.

The array should look like this:

```
array(){
    '2018' => array(
        01 => array(
           01 => array(
              'ticket' => 0,
              'hours' => 0,
           ),
           02 => array(
              'ticket' => 0,
              'hours' => 0,
           )
        )
    )
}
```

As stated the only stipulation is that the start date should start at the start date and the end date should start at the end date.

Could someone point me in the right direction.

Cheers.

Comment: What is `$generals` supposed to be?

Comment: @WillardSolutions its just a bunch of general functions that do useful things like convert date from 27/01/2019 to 2019/01/27 00:00:00 etc

I didnt include it on this code, because if no date is present it creates its own date from a year ago today to present date without the generals class included

Comment: And where is this method: `chartItemVersion()`?

Comment: @WillardSolutions I have updated the code, sorry forgot to add that function within the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `makingQueryArray` function seems complicate  - I believe you should solve it differently.

You can use [dateperiod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) to get all days between 2 dates:

```
$startDate = '2010-10-01';
$endDate = '2010-10-05';
$period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($startDate), new DateInterval('P1D'), new DateTime($endDate));
```

Now You can loop on all days and set you array:

```
foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
   $d = explode("-", $value->format('Y-m-d'));
   $res[$d[0]][$d[1]][$d[2]] = array('ticket' => 0, 'hours' => 0);
}
```

`$res` will give you your desire output. Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/clEip)

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been searching on php.net all day today and could not find anything like this.

I did not even know that DatePeriod even existed.

Thank you